# Did Scooby-Doo and the original team of meddling kids ever uncover something that was supernatural or real?

Tags: comics, cartoon, scooby-doo

Almost every *[Scooby-Doo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo)* mystery was scifi/fantasy until they were debunked in the end. In all of the *Scooby-Doo* episodes and movies or comics (excluding anything with his nephew in it) is there even a single instance in which the original gang of meddling kids in *Mystery, Inc.* solve something that was supernatural or real?

Comment: By original, do you mean in the original series _Scooby Doo, Where Are You?_  Or are you including the later incarnations, such as when Scrappy was added, or _The New Scooby Doo Movies_ or the revival, _What's New, Scooby Doo?_  Even if you include only the original 5 (Scooby, Freddie, Daphne, Velma, and Shaggy), there's still several incarnations of the stories that include only them and also several shows that includes _some_ of them that include supernatural events.

Comment: Anything with the original gang of five, the whole five, and only the five (plus celebrity guest stars)

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Comment: That's my point. From my admittedly very poor familiarity, it's not fantasy, it's mystery with a talking dog.

Comment: It's on topic, because it is asking about a supernatural (scifi/fantasy) element of a cartoon.

Comment: There was that one time when Sam and Dean got zapped into an episode.

Comment: Actually unless one limits supernatural incidents to original series the question is trivial.  In the later series it is probably harder to find NON-supernatural plots.

Comment: Well, there is a talking dog in the series. Does that count for anything?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, they did. I'm not sure of the details but [Scooby saw the real Loch Ness Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo!_and_the_Loch_Ness_Monster) after the gang solved the mystery.

Comment: +1 for being right.  That was one of the ones in the direct to video series.  There were also real aliens and ghosts in that series.

Comment: It looks like the *first* examples of real ghosts/monsters were in [The New Scooby-Doo Movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Scooby-Doo_Movies) which aired from 1972-1974 on CBS--the wiki article says it "deviated from the established Scooby-Doo format of presenting criminals masquerading as supernatural beings by introducing real ghosts, witches, monsters, and other such characters into the plots."

Comment: If "uncovered" is considered an operative word, then no.  A real ghost or monster often appeared to tease Scooby or Shaggy at the end.  But it was never part of the mystery, and if memory serves, it never revealed itself to the entire gang.  Could be wrong about that last, though.

Answer (score 30):

Yes.  In [Scooby Doo on Zombie Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo_on_Zombie_Island), they encounter real undead and werecats.  In digging deeper, most of the direct-to-video Scooby Doo movies in this era also feature real supernatural creatures.

[Scooby Doo (2002)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0267913/) featured real demons.
[Scooby Doo 2, Monsters Unleashed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0331632/) contained real monsters, although they were brought to life through "scientific" means and might not really fit the bill as "Supernatural".

Comment: I feel like there was a whole series of movies where the gang found real monsters.  One might have been called "Ghoul School?"

Comment: @AdeleC - Yep.  I Googled it,and you're right.  Apparently there are a LOT of Scooby Doo movies with real spooks.

Comment: @AdeleC Ghoul School was a Scrappy-Doo add-on.

Comment: @MajorStackings Scrappy Doo delenda est!

Comment: @MajorStackings a Scrap-On, if you will...

Answer (score 16):

In the original series, episode 16 "A Night of Fright is No Delight," the gang catch the two giggling green ghosts who are revealed to be crooked lawyers. However, at the very end they encounter a floating bone which appears to be genuinely supernatural. Fortunately this is the one type of ghost that Scooby isn't afraid of and he promptly chews it.

[image: "A floating haunted bone!"]

Obviously it's a silly joke but there's no indication that it isn't real and the gang don't seem particularly surprised at proof of ghosts.

Comment: Actually this is probably the most non trivial answer.  The original series was very rational so if that bone was genuinely supernatural it very much should be noted.

Answer (score 4):

On the sci-fi side of things, [*Scooby-Doo and the Cyber Chase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo_and_the_Cyber_Chase) had them fighting a "computer virus" (blue guy who lives in a computer), in cyberspace (VR, sort of?).  Although the virus does put on a number of themed outfits throughout the story, none of them really qualify as disguises because they fool neither the audience nor any of the characters.  So in this sense, he may be described as "real" because he was not wearing a disguise and was not unmasked at the end.

Note that any resemblance to actual computer science (or indeed physics) is purely coincidental.  This is very far on the soft end of the sci-fi scale.

Answer (score 4):

Yes in Scooby Doo and the Witch's Ghost.

A horror story writer tricks the gang into helping him find a spell book with a spell that allowed him to summon, get this a witch's ghost. (Attention to detail.)

Sources:

- https://scoobydoo.fandom.com/wiki/Scooby-Doo_and_the_Witch%27s_Ghost
- I personally saw it 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers, there's also a newer animated Scooby Doo TV series called [*Scooby-Doo! Mystery Incorporated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo!_Mystery_Incorporated) ([TVTROPES WARNING TvTropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/ScoobyDooMysteryIncorporated)), contemporary with your question, which has supernatural elements.  The original team of five looks into the mysteries of the town of Crystal Cove, and eventually uncover supernatural elements.  I haven't watched this series and don't know much about the story, but apaprently extraterrestrial aliens are involved.

Comment: SD:MI is not "the original". It specifically goes for a self-conscious spoof of the original toons, including several instances of supernatural phenomena which the gang manages to ignore as if it weren't abnormal at all.